# Convert a PDA to a DFA

Tags: automata, dfa, pushdown-automaton

I am looking to convert a PDA to a DFA. Where the stack of the PDA will never contain more then n number of symbols.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have no complete solution but just an idea: For each transition which pushes a symbol *s* on the stack you must copy the subgraph to the next pop transitions. The new subgraph must accept the same substring as the corresponding subgraph in the PDA for *s*. When you search for such transitions you must go from inside out, such that there no inner pushes and pops in the subgraph. Thus the first replacements will consist of two transistions, and the further subgraphs become larger and larger.